# How to use CloudFireStore on Android Stuido

Tags: android, firebase

**I want to use CloudFireStore From Firebase**
How can I start It on Android Studio Project

> Firebase : CloudFireStore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*if you are new about firebase servisces you just follow the link*
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

*or you can just open your project in android studio go to* **Tools>Firebase>Firestore**

*login to android studio if you are not login already*

Answer (score 0):

simply you just need to make your first project on firebase then make colection, document and the value from firestore and auth it on ur android studio or `you can search on youtube project`